# Prove correctness of a partial derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have the matrix a $6 \times 10$ matrix $\mathbf(M)$, $6 \times 2$ matrix $\mathbf(A)$, and a $2 \times 10$ matrix $\mathbf(B)$. Then I have
$$
E(A,B) = \sum_{i = 1}^{6}\sum_{j = 1}^{10}\mathbf{I}_{ij}(\mathbf{M}_{ij} - (a_{i1}b_{1j}+a_{i2}b_{2j}))^2
$$

Now I wonder, for any $k \in \{1,...,6\}, l \in \{1,...,10\}, m \in \{1,2\}$ how do you prove step by step that the following partial derivative is correct:
$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial a_{km}}
= 2 \cdot \sum_{j=1}^{10} I_{kj} 
(-M_{kj} \cdot b_{mj}
+ b_{mj} \cdot a_{k1} \cdot b_{1j}
+ b_{mj} \cdot a_{k2} \cdot b_{2j})
$$

Comment: Have you tried using the product rule together with the identity $\frac{\partial a_{ij}}{\partial a_{kl}} = \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}$ (where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta)?

Comment: What is $\mathbf{I}_{ij}$?  I gather it is the $(i,j)$-th entry of a $6\times 10$ matrix, but is it connected to the identity matrix?

Comment: You asked this exact same question on September 21.  I answered it, but you deleted it. Then you asked it again on September 22. I commented on that post that I had answered the same question the night before. Then you deleted that post. Now you’ve asked this question a third time. Are you ready to accept an answer? Or are you going to delete it and re-ask the question, again?

Answer (score 0):

Your $E(A,B)$ consists of $60$ summands. If we want to compute ${\partial E\over\partial a_{km}}$ for given $k$ and $m$ we only have to look at the summands with $i=k$, since the others do not contain the variable $a_{km}$. We therefore have to differentiate the quantity
$$\hat E:=\sum_{j=1}^{10} I_{kj}\bigl(a_{k1}b_{1j}+a_{k2}b_{2j}-M_{kj}\bigr)^2$$
with respect to $a_{km}$. Note that
$${\partial\over\partial a_{km}}\bigl(a_{k1}b_{1j}+a_{k2}b_{2j}-M_{kj}\bigr)=b_{mj}\qquad\bigl(m\in\{1,2\}\bigr)\ .$$
It follows that
$${\partial E\over\partial a_{km}}={\partial\hat E\over\partial a_{km}}=2\sum_{j=1}^{10}I_{kj}\bigl(a_{k1}b_{1j}+a_{k2}b_{2j}-M_{kj}\bigr)b_{mj}\ ,$$
which coincides with your claim.